# AnAction. Set text to the right

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

When I press cmd + shift + a there is such a search:

[image]

I think that to output the result used a list of AnAction or custom analog. I'm interested in how to add the text to the right (example: New, Goto Goto by Name Actions, File, Goto by Reference Actions).

In my plugin I use ComboBoxAction with DefaultActionGroup which have list of AnAction.
I want an element in this ComboBoxAction to look like as on screenshot above that is:
Icon Text RightText.

Here is my ComboboxAction and where highlighted in red I want to add some text

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: The text on the right is the name of the action group in which the action is contained. I guess you can wrap each of your actions into an action group and specify the name of that group...

Comment: I tried to do so:
`protected open inner class MyActionGroup : ActionGroup("group text", "group description", Icons.test_icon) {
        override fun getChildren(e: AnActionEvent?): Array<AnAction> {
            return arrayOf(object : AnAction("action text", "action description", Icons.test_icon) {
                override fun actionPerformed(e: AnActionEvent?) {}
            })
        }
    }
...
defaultActionGroup.add(MyActionGroup())
`
AnAction appears, but the group name is not